# Mongoose - Sub Document Array Issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a "Company" Model which has a number of "Rooms".

I'm able to create the Rooms no problem, and they have a link back to the Company.

The problem is that when I get the Company, the Rooms array has no items.

I can see that the Room exists and has a link back to the Company:

```
{
    "RoomType": 0,
    "AllowedRoomRoles": [
        "5f999f4f542eed1b8fce5fa9"
    ],
    "Enabled": true,
    "_id": "5fb677b453658c7070bf9433",
    "RoomName": "Martins Room 2",
    "RoomPin": "0001",
    "Company": "5fad553db19ca100161a0d8f",
    "__v": 0
}
```

However when I do:
var company = await CompanyModel.findById('5fad553db19ca100161a0d8f');

I get the Company back but the Rooms array has no items in it.

Here are my models:

````
//Room Schema:

const roomSchema = new Schema({
RoomPin: String,
  RoomName: String,
  RoomType: { type: RoomType, default: RoomType.MeetingRoom } ,
  Company: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CompanySchema'},
  AllowedRoomRoles: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'RoomRoleSchema'}],
  Enabled: { type: Boolean, default: true },
}, {
    collection: "room"
})

//Company Schema:

const companySchema = new Schema({
  CompanyName: { type: String, required: true },
  CompanyLogo: { type: String, required: true },
  Enabled: { type: Boolean, default: true },
  CompanyIdentifier: { type: String, required: true },
  CompanyWebsite: { type: String, required: true },
  Rooms: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'RoomSchema'}],
}, {
    collection: "company"
})

Minor update:

Seems doing it this way around is fine?

```var rooms = await RoomModel.find({'Company': company._id.toString() });
````

Comment: idk much of this but `Rooms: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'RoomSchema'}] ` shouldn't the type be different?

Comment: I don't think so, the model is registered using that name: const RoomModel = model<IRoom & Document>('RoomSchema', roomSchema);